# Export Filtered Worksheet as CSV File

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I am currently using this code to export the whole sheet, but I would like to only export the rows where a condition is met. In this case in Column 13 there is an "x":

```
Option Explicit
Sub ExportAsCSV()

Dim MyFileName As String
Dim CurrentWB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

Set CurrentWB = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy

Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
  .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
End With        

Dim Change below to "- 4"  to become compatible with .xls files
MyFileName = CurrentWB.Path & "\" & Left(CurrentWB.Name, Len(CurrentWB.Name) - 5) & ".csv"

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TempWB.SaveAs Filename:=MyFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

I tried to adapt the code with an autofilter but was not successful.
I replaced the line

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
```

with this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$M$81").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="x"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

But I am getting the Autofiltermethod of Range Class failed error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it is easier to get rid of what you don't want instead of making a copy of what you do want.

```
Sub ExportAsCSV()
    Dim myFileName As String

    With ActiveWorkbook
        myFileName = Left(.FullName, InStrRev(.Name, Chr(46)) - 1) 'note no extension needed
        .ActiveSheet.Copy   'makes a copy in a new active workbook
    End With

    'new ActiveWorkbook with copy of worksheet
    With ActiveWorkbook
        With .Worksheets(1)
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
                .Value = .Value
                .AutoFilter field:=13, criteria1:="<>x"
                With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                    If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                End With
            End With
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
        .SaveAs Filename:=myFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Using your code gives me an error in the line:.     AutoFilter field:=13, criteria:="<>x"

Comment: Thank you very much this is working as intended now. Could you give me a hint which part to modify to specify where I want the csv file saved and what name it is supposed to have?

Comment: Your original code for MyFileName construction could more easily be modified for that. Personally, I prefer not to add extension since filetype:=xlcsv adds the correct one.

Comment: Okay thank you I will try my luck as I have a specific folder these csv files get saved to.

Answer (score 1):

Before using auto filter command select the cell and apply the autofilter

```
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("M1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$APX$1000").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:="x"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
```

by using this code your sheet will be filtered,
Thank You.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, using your solution the filtering of the original sheet indeed works, but the exported csv file is empty.